# Lazarus - open a text file on another machine

Tags: windows, ubuntu, text-files, remote-access, lazarus

I am doing a simple program on Lazarus to read a text file on my Ubuntu server (via LAN).

I cannot get passed this line:

```
AssignFile(TheFile,'//My-server-IP/home/myusername/folder/abc.txt');
```

I get an error saying **Access denied**.
I've set the file's permission to 777 but no success.

I even tried using the path: **//My-server-IP/var/www/folder/abc.txt** but have the same result.

The client machine is Windows XP. But can be even Windows 7 or anything.

Any thoughts on getting around this issue are really valued.

Comment: Can you open the file from within Windows Explorer on the client machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//server/share/file is not a windows notation of UNC paths. Maybe you mean \server\share\file ?

I'm not sure if the FPC filename handling supports UNC. It is mostly based on Win32 -A functions, but tries to done some extra sanitizing of filenames.

Note that access outside the windows explorer will probably not autologin for you.

Comment: Thanks Marco for your tip... So are you saying that I'll never be able to open the file sitting on the Ubuntu server through a client program running on the workstation? Perhaps you're right. I renamed the file path like you said (\\server\home\user\folder...) but I still get **Access Denied**.

Comment: As said accessing a file by unc path does not automatically make a connection. That happens when accessing through windows explorer (which manages connections as part of its functionality), but not using cmdline or by programmatic means. So you will have to research api functions (like WNetAddConnection*) to make connections